# MATLAB stereo calibration result is different when point pairs are reordered

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

When I change the image file names' order (simultaneously change the lists `imageFileNames1` and `imageFileNames2`), the calibration result `stereoParams` is different (although little difference). Why?

Example code is as follows:

**First calibration:**

```
imageFileNames1 = {'F:\CaptureFiles\left01.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left02.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left03.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left04.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left05.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left06.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left07.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left08.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left09.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left10.bmp',...
    };
imageFileNames2 = {'F:\CaptureFiles\right01.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right02.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right03.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right04.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right05.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right06.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right07.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right08.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right09.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right10.bmp',...
    };

% Detect checkerboards in images
[imagePoints, boardSize, imagesUsed] = detectCheckerboardPoints(imageFileNames1, imageFileNames2);

% Generate world coordinates of the checkerboard keypoints
squareSize = 50;  % in units of 'mm'
worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize, squareSize);

% Calibrate the camera
[stereoParams, pairsUsed, estimationErrors] = estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints, worldPoints, ...
    'EstimateSkew', false, 'EstimateTangentialDistortion', false, ...
    'NumRadialDistortionCoefficients', 2, 'WorldUnits', 'mm', ...
    'InitialIntrinsicMatrix', [], 'InitialRadialDistortion', []);
```

**Second calibration(changle list of imageFileNames):**

```
imageFileNames1 = {'F:\CaptureFiles\left01.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left06.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left07.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left08.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left09.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left10.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left02.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left03.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left04.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\left05.bmp',...
    };
imageFileNames2 = {'F:\CaptureFiles\right01.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right06.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right07.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right08.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right09.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right10.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right02.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right03.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right04.bmp',...
    'F:\CaptureFiles\right05.bmp',...
    };

% Detect checkerboards in images
[imagePoints, boardSize, imagesUsed] = detectCheckerboardPoints(imageFileNames1, imageFileNames2);

% Generate world coordinates of the checkerboard keypoints
squareSize = 50;  % in units of 'mm'
worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize, squareSize);

% Calibrate the camera
[stereoParams, pairsUsed, estimationErrors] = estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints, worldPoints, ...
    'EstimateSkew', false, 'EstimateTangentialDistortion', false, ...
    'NumRadialDistortionCoefficients', 2, 'WorldUnits', 'mm', ...
    'InitialIntrinsicMatrix', [], 'InitialRadialDistortion', []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [estimateCameraParameters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimatecameraparameters.html):

> Camera calibration estimates the values of the intrinsic parameters, the extrinsic parameters, and the distortion coefficients. There are two steps involved in camera calibration:
>
> 1. Solve for the intrinsics and extrinsics in closed form, assuming that lens distortion is zero.
> 2. Estimate all parameters simultaneously including the distortion coefficients using nonlinear least-squares minimization (Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm). Use the closed form solution from the preceding step as the initial estimate of the intrinsics and extrinsics. Then set the initial estimate of the distortion coefficients to zero.

Numerical differences can occur when reordering the point pairs in both these stages.

1. Reordering of the equations can have a slight effect on the results of [numerical least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)).
2. The [iterative minimization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)  may use the data only in parts for speed, and even if not it is again solving (damped) linear equations and so may slightly be affected by the reordering.

This can only explain small numerical differences. Anything more than this has to be explained by some undocumented step of the algorithm (e.g. [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus)) or by the equations being very ill-conditioned.